# failed to read artifact descriptor for jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

i create a Spring web application using start.spring.io to generate simple project starter with some settings and dependencies. Details below:

```
project: maven project
language: java
spring boot: 2.4.0
project metadata:
- group: id.pinsiot
- artifact: splash
- name: splash
- description: splash
- package name: splash
- packaging: jar
- java: 11
dependencies:
- spring boot devtools
- spring web
- thymeleaf
```

After download and generate the project from the spring website, i open the zip file and extract it to my local computer. Then i open a IDE eclipse, details below:

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212
```

i'm open the project with this steps: `file -> import -> existing maven projects`

below the error logs:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:352)
///and there's many logs, i cant paste all of logs here.
```

here's the screenshot from eclipse:
[image: jakarta.activation.api]

additional notes:

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)

apache tomcat 9.0.37
```

any solution? what i've to do?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or require any kind of proxy setup for Eclipse to access the Internet?

Comment: @nitind i'm not sure about that, how to check it?

Comment: Then you probably don't. Clear your local Maven repository and try again.

Comment: @nitind do i have to close the eclipse first before clean local maven repository?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @nitind i'm delete m2 folder located in `C:\Users\myname\m2`, turning off firewall public and private, then open eclipse, navigate to my project `right click -> run as -> maven install`. It's still return the same error :(